# Make thumbnail of multiple pages from PDF wiith imagemagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, thumbnails

I've worked out how to make nice thumbnails from single-page PDFs. But as my below code shows the best I can do for 2+ page PDFs is to choose to do the first page:

```
$w=320;$h=240;
$fname="my.pdf";
$saveFname = "mypdf.jpg";

$im = new \imagick($fname);
if($im->getNumberImages()>=2){
    $im->setiteratorindex(0);   //Just do first page
    }
$im->thumbnailImage($w,$h,/*bestfit=*/true,/*fill=*/true);
$im->writeImage($saveFname);
```

What I'd like to do is have pages 1 and 2 side-by-side, and making best use of the available space. (If there is an option to do tiling of all pages, or selected pages, then even better.)

I thought `montageImage` might be the answer, but I cannot find a complete example, so could not work out how to specify the PDF pages to process.

**Notes on above listing:**

- The 3rd parameter to thumbnailImage means it keeps the aspect ratio of the original
- The 4th parameter means pad (with white) on either side so the image is still $w x $h pixels
- You can append [n] to $fname to just load page n (counting from zero) (e.g. "my.pdf[0]" makes a thumbnail of the first page).
- By default it will do the last page of a multi-page PDF, so `setiteratorindex()` is needed to select the page to process.

Answer (score 3):

**Modified Version**

This may do what you want more simply!

```
montage -density 288 input.pdf[0,1] -resize 50% -mode Concatenate -tile 2x thumb.jpg
```

**Original Solution**

I am not sure how you would do it in `php`, but here is a script that does what I think you want at the command line with ImageMagick:

```
#!/bin/bash
PDF=$1
TMPA="TMPA-$$.JPG"
TMPB="TMPB-$$.JPG"
out=1
#
# Get number of pages in PDF
NUMPAGES=$(identify "$PDF" | wc -l)
echo $PDF has $NUMPAGES pages
#
# Iterate over all pages, two at a time
for ((p=0;p<$NUMPAGES;))
do
    convert -density 288 a.pdf[$p] -alpha remove -resize 50% "$TMPA"
    ((p++))
    convert -density 288 a.pdf[$p] -alpha remove -resize 50% "$TMPB"
    ((p++))
    convert +append "$TMPA" "$TMPB" thumb${out}.jpg
    ((out++))
    rm "$TMPA" "$TMPB" 2> /dev/null
done
```

Save as `thumbnailer` and use like this:

```
chmod +x thumbnailer
./thumbnailer xyz.pdf
```

It produces a "twos-up" output of the PDF, in thumbnail files `thumb{1..n/2}.jpg`

Hopefully there are some hints in there as to what parameters to use and what functions to call in `php.